# Prevent multiple purchases with the same credit card?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authorize.net, activemerchant, pci-compliance

I'm thinking through how to develop a validation on my Rails app that essentially checks to make sure that the credit card used for any given transaction by any user is unique in our system, such that all credit card may be used to purchase an item only **once** across the entire application for all users, for all time.

The thinking behind this restriction is that this app will sometimes run time-sensitive promotional deals, and we want to do our best to institute a "one purchase per credit card" system for these deals.

I was thinking of hashing the credit card number and just storing that hash in the db, then cross-referencing it at the time of each new purchase (so my payment gateway keeps the actual number, and I just keep a hash in the DB), but [on further research, this seems like a bad idea](http://www.integrigy.com/security-resources/whitepapers/Integrigy_Hashing_Credit_Card_Numbers_Unsafe_Practices.pdf).

So I'm back to the drawing board and looking for new ideas. Anyone know a good approach to this problem, while keeping as PCI-compliant as I can be?

I'm developing with Rails 3 and using ActiveMerchant to integrate with my payment gateway, Authorize.net, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong direction.  I would just check last 4 of card, ip and shipping addresses.  The risks of storing that data versus the damage if a small number of users gamed the last 4 & ip solution is not worth it.  (He says not knowing the nature of the purchases.)

Since address isn't collected...First 4, Last 4 and 4 Digit Expiration (all hashed of course) should provide the uniqueness you need to ensure that card was only used once.

Comment: My hang up here about using the last four digits only is that it would be easy to spoof the IP address and just use the same card over and over again, even without changing the shipping address. I agree that I want to minimize my risks with storing that data, but I'd need a good alternative to reasonably guarantee that the card cannot be used more than once without significant effort to circumvent whatever solution I end up adopting.

Comment: That's why I said the bit about not knowing the value of the item.  Spoofing IP address for a discount is *usually* not worth the effort. Check the shipping address...only one item per address first 3-5 chars of street + zip with last 4 and ip and that should hit the 95% + range.

Comment: In our case, we've had past instances of users gaming the system by spoofing their IPs--a number significant enough to look at making sure that won't be a problem again, which brought my thinking to checking hashed #s. Our problem is compounded in that 90% of our products do not require a shipping address, so it's not really an option to use that either (the products are digital).

Comment: You *could* do the same with the billing address...first 3-5 chars + zip + hash of last 4 + a hash of their UserAgent string...they could switch browsers but that would probably limit to like 2 purchases if they were sneaky.  Billing address would technically be better than the card anyway cuz presumably they'd use the same address for different cards.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I feel about billing address either; we're currently not employing AVS (may need to change that, still researching) so billing address might not be provided either. I definitely don't feel comfortable including the UserAgent string, as that's far to variable (in my opinion) to be trusted. Any other thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7325/discussion-between-neezer-and-webjedi)

Comment: Using a billing address is almost a good solution - assuming there's validation at billing time. BUT it'll prevent legitimate multi-dwellers (roomates, same family) from getting the discount.  IP address isn't helpful because (a) it can be spoofed and (b) almost everyone has another IP they can use (work computer, library computer, friends house, cell phone access, Tor, Proxy...).  If the issue is prevent abuse why don't you just make the process of obtaining the discount tricker - mail in rebate, registered against an account which requires an address and some kind of proof.

Comment: Hash of last 4 + hash of zip (assuming you use that for validation, if not I'd turn that on) has got to cover 99% I would think. Right?  That would only prevent 1 purchase per card though...adding billing address could restrict it to person.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Just a note to the rest of SO here that I'm accepting the second part of @Webjedi's answer here. Ideally, I should be incorporating AVS in to this equation as well, but we're not currently using it, so I think this is the best solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly some hashing is a bad idea - either because it's low security, has some intercepts, or so commonly used there's rainbow tables.  That doesn't mean all hashing is a bad idea - the only way to cross reference is going to be some way of uniquely and predictably identifying the information.  Unless PCI specifically prohibits it - hashing is still the way to go.

**Salt**

Make sure you salt your hash - this prevents rainbow attacks, or at least requires the rainbow-attacker build a table with your salt in mind.  In particular if you can keep the salt reasonably secure {I say only reasonably because in order to generate you need to have the salt which means it'll be in code somewhere}.

**Choose a Good Algorithm**

While MD5 is now infamous, and implemented in all kinds of languages, it's also so common that you can find pre-made rainbow tables.  It's also extremely quick to generate a hash.  Your system can probably tolerate a small amount of delay, and use a much more processor-intensive hash.  This makes the cost of generating a rainbow table much more expensive.  Check out the [Tiger algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29) for example.

**Hash more than once**

If you have multiple related data points, multiple hashes are going to make it way harder to do a rainbow attack.  For example: Hash(Hash(Card#+salt1)+expireDate+salt2) - requires knowledge of both the card # and the date to generate (easy for you) but can't easily be reverse-engineered (rainbow requires for every card # * every useful expire date + knowledge of both salts).

**Edit:** (your comments)

*Reasonably secure*: Only transmit it over an encrypted connection (SFTP, SSH), don't store it unencrypted - including live/iterative and backup copies, keep the file with the salt outside of the web tree (cannot be directly accessed/accidentally released), make sure permissions on the file are as restrictive as possible (don't allow group/global file access).

*Dynamic salt* throwing a random value into the hash is great for reducing rainbow attacks - you store that random piece in the table with the hashed value - now when building a rainbow you have to build one for every dynamic salt.  However for your needs you can't do this - you need to know the right random salt to use the second time you create the hash (otherwise you'll never get an intercept on the second card use)... for that to be predictable/repeatable you'd then have to base the dynamic salt on some part of the number... which is effectively what multiple hashing with another data point does.  The more data points you have the more you can hash in this direction - if you have the CVV for example (3 hashes), or perhaps you hash 8 digits at a time (for a total of 3 hashes: `hash(hash(hash(1..8+salt1)+9..16+salt2)+expDate+salt3)`).

*Best Hash* it's a moving target, but there's a good [discussion on security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/most-secure-password-hash-algorithms).  Which points to SHA-512.

Comment: Good points all around, though I'm still not sure how "reasonably secure" my salt would be in my code. The PDF I linked to suggested having a dynamic salt, but I feel like that would make it harder to to verify genuineness. What are your thoughts about BCrypt instead of MD5? I'll fully admit I'm still not that knowledgeable about cryptography...

Comment: Thanks for the extra info; very helpful. I'm trying to figure out what sort of hashing would be best both to protect our customer data as well as protect our business; reading through the compliance guide now (https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI%20SSC%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide.pdf). Do you think hashing the last 4 digits + CVV code with a secure salt via SHA-512 is a good approach? Would that be unique across all cards, or would there be cases where cards would have the same last 4 digits & CVV code?

Comment: From what I know never ever ever store the CVV hashed, encrypted, put on a zip drive and hidden in the underwear drawer or anyway else.

Comment: @Webjedi Fair point; felt smelly anyway. :) Gonna have to clean out all those zip drives in my underwear drawer now...

Comment: Last 4 digits are totally useless - easily and often repeating across cards.  If that's the case with CVVs then lets ignore those ;)

Comment: @Webjedi Ahh, just got to page 15 of the document I linked to earlier, and you're right: merchants are not permitted to store CVV codes, via PCI.

Answer (score 1):

faking your true [credit card number online](http://www.creditcardshelplines.com/credit-card-generator.html#axzz1lQPO9Taa) is the best way to prevent this from happening. Citibank clients can login and make use of this tool provided with all accounts. Just generate a number and exp date for use online, and all is fine , for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "one purchase per user" system then why don't you just check the user's purchase history whenever they try to buy a special-purchase item to ensure that they haven't bought it previously?

Comment: Because I also want to make sure that another user doesn't use the same card that the first user used. So I guess it's more like "one purchase per credit card" than "per user"...

Answer (score 0):

user could register for multiple accounts.

although by checking users history, as well as enforcing 1 item per address for each purchase- you will likely be fine- you could also limit things by users name/ birthday/ whatever other identifying information.

Credit Card information can also change by the way- its actually very easy to purchase 100 gift credit cards with unique numbers so if you want to police things down to the most minute level... I dont think you will be able to just by cc numbers

Comment: Good point about the gift credit cards; I hadn't thought about that. I'm also recording the user's IP address (which I know can also be spoofed), but I'm hoping that the IP combined with the hashed CC number might be enough to deter 90% of attempts to circumvent.

Comment: Don't hash the full # if you can avoid it.  Don't make yourself a target unnecessarily.

Comment: I'd rather not hash the full #, frankly... but I do need a reliable way to prevent a card from being used more than once when purchasing items from out site. If I don't used the hashed #, what else could I use?